# Use Javascript to parse a sub-array of a JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I'm working with some JSON objects about homes. The JSON looks like the below. How would I use Javascript parsing to pull out the "yearBuilt" value? It's part of the building array, which is part of the parcel array.

I've explored looping based on other similar asked-questions, but can't arrive at anything that seems to work. Thanks!

```
{
   "home_value":298900,
   "page_url":"https://www.example.com/",
   "parcel":{
      "address":{
         "full":"123 Main Street",
         "city":"Raleigh",
         "state":"NC",
         "house":"2856",
         "houseExt":null,
         "street":"Jameson",
         "streetPre":"W",
         "streetPost":null,
         "streetSuffix":"Rd",
         "unit":null,
         "unitType":null,
         "zip":"27604",
         "zip4":"3776"
      },
      "apn":"1725.14-22-9727 0145193",
      "areas":[
         {
            "type":"Heated Building Area",
            "areaSquareFeet":1574
         },
         {
            "type":"Calculated Finished Area",
            "areaSquareFeet":1574
         }
      ],
      "building":[
         {
            "noOfUnits":1,
            "class":null,
            "classDescription":null,
            "quality":null,
            "condition":null,
            "architecturalStyle":"Conventional",
            "yearBuilt":1986,
            "effectiveYearBuilt":1986,
            "totalStories":2,
            "totalRooms":null,
            "bedrooms":null,
            "kitchens":null,
            "fullBaths":2,
            "baths":2,
            "comments":null,
            "occupancyStatus":"Assumed Owner Occupancy",
            "heating":"Forced air",
            "airConditioning":"Yes",
            "foundation":null,
            "fireplace":null,
            "water":null,
            "sewer":null,
            "quarterBaths":null,
            "halfBaths":0,
            "threeQuarterBaths":null
         }
      ],
      "state":"NC",
      "zoningCode":null,
      "zoningDescription":"R-6",
      "zpid":"6487528",
      "county":"Wake County"
   }
}
```

Comment: What _did_ you arrive at? How do its outputs differ from your expectations? Give a [mre].

Comment: `parcel` isn't an array, maybe that's where you went wrong.

Comment: `value.parcel.building[i].yearBuilt`